# Trying to find folders that only contain one file

Tags: macos, find

I would like a find command (or similar) that when pointed at a folder, it would list all the files that live inside that folder or any of its subfolders, but only if the folder contains a single file. To put it another way, I want to list the contents of folders that only contain one file.

So given the following files

```
/Foldera/folderb
/Foldera/folderb/test1.txt
/Foldera/folderb/test2.txt
/Foldera/folderc
/Foldera/folderd/test3.txt
/Foldera/folderc/foldere
```

it would output

```
/Foldera/folderd/test3.txt
```

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: osx 10.9.1 (Mavericks)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Bash 3:

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c \
'[[ $(find "$0" -mindepth 1 | wc -l) -eq 1 ]] && [[ $(find "$0" -mindepth 1 -type d | wc -l) -eq 0 ]]  && echo "$0"' \
{} \;
```

With Bash 4:

```
shopt -s globstar
for dir in **/; do 
  [[ $(find "$dir" -mindepth 1 | wc -l) -eq 1 ]] && [[ $(find "$dir" -mindepth 1 -type d | wc -l) -eq 0 ]]  && echo "$dir"
done
```

In essence, iterate over every directory and then check if that directory contains exactly one child (either file or directory), and check if that child is not a directory. If there is exactly one child and it's not a directory, `echo` it.

Be advised: this fails if directories or files contain a newline in their name.

It might be easier to do if you had GNU utilities such as `find` with a `-printf` option but OS X does not have that by default.

Comment: I actually got round to trying this today, and the bash3 script actually lists folders with one file rather than the files within, could this be changed ? I dont seem to have bash4 so the second script doesnt work complaining globstar doesnt work.

Comment: For that, all you'd have to change the `echo "$0"` to `find "$0"`.

Comment: thx, ok final thing Ive realized I need the path output to be the complete path, not relative to starting location, how can I do that please ?

Comment: okay worked out, just pass path as parameter, and use find $1 instead of find ., and make sure path provided is absolute not relative

Answer (score -1):

I don't have a Mac to test this on but I found lots of answers when I googled your question.

```
find . -type 'f' -printf '%h\n' | sort | uniq -c
```

That will print how many files are in each folder, and then using grep or some other tool you can narrow it down.

I would check out the source below, it's for Windows but they have lots of perl solutions that might work just as well.

Similar Question: [Source](https://serverfault.com/questions/74484/how-to-find-directories-that-contain-only-one-file)

Comment: That doesn't work on OS X 10.9 because it does not ship with GNU `find` but BSD `find` which does not have a `-printf` option. See: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html